# Case-insensitive ignoreCase - text field

Tags: webforms

i am trying to create a text field that accepts case-insensitive text but be unique.

Hassan is hAssan is haSsan...etc

i have tried a different combinations of regex with no success. i would be thankful if someone could help out with this.

where can i suggest if J could add a toggle switch (ignoreCase on/off)?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unique to what? Unique to all existing submissions? Then you need custom element validation querying the database for all existing submissions.

Comment: webform has a toggle unique to the text field... so it is a unique entry for that field. this is how it works (i guess)... so if i created a text field called email and switched the unique toggle on it should check for the entries of that field... in the current state of things... hassan@blahblah unique... and if i enter Hassan@blahblah it would see it as a different value.

Comment: Wow, TIL that Webform indeed has this built-in already: https://git.drupalcode.org/project/webform/-/blob/6.1.x/src/Plugin/WebformElementBase.php#L1976-2056. I see that you disabled all the unique checkboxes. Please try to have only the "Unique" one selected and the other ones disabled. If this still doesn't work, try to remove the pattern as well.

Comment: If it's case insensitive you should file a feature request issue on https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/webform.

Comment: thanks a ton leymannx... i have tried all the combinations... i just didn't upload the screen shots... i filed a bug / feature request. the only thing i did not test is email uniqueness... i don't know if webform has a specific email field... I'm sure hassan@hy.ae and HASSAN@hy.ae are the same. so the case sensitivity or insensitivity is something that webform has already ...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a bug report on the module.

Comment: i agree... i filed a bug and jrock responded that "This might not be fixable because some SQL engines have case-insensitive queries." i'll do some digging and lets see if gpt-4 can propose something... do i close this thread ? or someone had to do it .?